# PySpark dataframe error: ava.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: apache-spark

Consider [this parquet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C0fQdr21XYIqNjpjSzTBFhV8eEJs8zTQ/view?usp=sharing). I ran the following code on it:

```
nis = spark.read.parquet(PATH)
nis.show()
nis.filter('mixed is null').show()
```

Output is:

```
+-------+---------+-----+
|nonulls|onlynulls|mixed|
+-------+---------+-----+
| value1|     null|  one|
| value2|     null| null|
| value3|     null|  two|
+-------+---------+-----+
```

[...]

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o201.showString.: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 10.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 10.0 (TID 25) (10.250.33.73 executor 32): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 3 out of bounds for length 3
```

The error is generated by each of the columns - every time I filter by 'is null' or 'is not null' it fails (except when the result of the filter is an empty dataframe).

What causes this problem? Is PySpark unable to filter nulls?

Comment: Interesting! I'm not super familiar with pyspark and using actual SQL queries in your operations but could you show the query plans for both? In Scala it would be something like: `ndf.filter('b is null').explain` and `g2.filter('b is null').explain`. Comparing these will give you a clue into how they are different.

Comment: You may be right but still, can you show the full stacktrace?

Comment: Is there a way for us to reproduce your problem? Not asking for the entire file here, but it might be possible to generate sample data that still triggers the issue. BTW, doing so might also help you pin point the source of the problem.

Comment: Does your parquet file contain very large strings?